# C++11 Get non-default constructed object as output parameter

Tags: c++11

I have a custom method that pops an object from a queue of **value** objects as out parameter and returns an error code:

```
class Element
{
public:
    Element() = delete;

    Element(int32_t a, const std::string &s)
    {
        a_ = a;
        s_ = s;
    }

private:
    int32_t a_;
    std::string s_;
}

enum class ErrorCode : uint32_t
{
    OK = 0,
    QueueEmpty,
    QueueFull
}

class QueueWrapper
{
public:
    ErrorCode push(const Element &e)
    {
        // Implementation
    }

    ErrorCode pop(Element &outE)
    {
        // Simple example

        if(queue_.empty())
        {
            return ErrorCode::QueueEmpty;
        }

        outE = queue_.front();
        queue_.pop();

        return ErrorCode::OK;
    }

private 
    std::queue<Element> queue_;
}

void function()
{
    QueueWrapper queueWrapper;

    Element e1(1, "1");
    ErrorCode errorCode = queueWrapper.push(e1);

    // What should I do here?
    // Element e2;
    // errorCode = queueWrapper.pop(e2);
}
```

Can I get a non-default constructed object as output parameter using *move* semantics or other mechanisms?

Comment: `Element pop(ErrorCode&);` As currently implemented, `pop` requires `Element` to implement an assignment operator - but the compiler can't generate one due to a member of reference type.

Comment: What does two-parameter `Element` constructor look like? You can't bind `s_` to `s`, so I wonder how `s_` is initialized. My guess is, you don't want `s_` to be a reference. Declare it as plain `std::string`, then your `pop` should work as written.

Comment: `Element(int32_t a, constant std::string &s);` should be `Element(int32_t a, const std::string &s);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the signature of `pop()` to return an Element and not an ErrorCode, then:

```
Element e( queueWrapper.pop() );
```

If you absolutely have to have the ErrorCode, pass it into `pop()` by reference. BUT error codes really aren't modern C++. Errors should mostly be handled with exceptions, leading to something more like this:

```
try {
    ...
    Element e( queueWrapper.pop() );
    ...
}
catch ( QueueWrapper::Exception & e )
{
    // exception handling/reporting
}
```

Error codes should really only be used for crossing module boundaries.

Comment: Note that have exceptions in `pop` is usually not exception-safe if it has to return the element too. You usually use a separate `top` and void-returning `pop` for that

Answer (score 0):

No. If you can form a reference to an `Element`, that means it has already be constructed (or it would be a segment of memory gibberish, not an `Element`).

If the behaviour you want is for the function to somehow get a designated space to construct the object into, let [(N)RVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) do the job.